# Windows Phone 8.1 camera initialization

Tags: c#, visual-studio, camera, windows-phone-8.1

I am aware about that there are more duplicate questions about this, but please, it is super important to me. I have hard time now with Windows Phone 8.1 C# camera initialization.

```
async private void InitCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        captureManager = new MediaCapture();
        await captureManager.InitializeAsync();

         try 
        {
            captureManager = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
            await captureManager.InitializeAsync();

            if (captureManager.MediaCaptureSettings.VideoDeviceId != "" && captureManager.MediaCaptureSettings.AudioDeviceId != "") 
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Init successful");


                captureManager.RecordLimitationExceeded += new Windows.Media.Capture.RecordLimitationExceededEventHandler(RecordLimitationExceeded);
                captureManager.Failed += new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureFailedEventHandler(Failed); 
            } 
            else 
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No Device");
            } 
        }
         catch (Exception exception)
         {
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception raised!!!!:" + exception);
         } 
    }
```

this is my code to initialize camera, but for some reason it fails on `Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture()` constructor call with `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` on Lumia 920 and also Access Violation on emulator. I've googled about the issue, but no answers so far. Some folks told that I should enable not just webcam, but also microphone, but that did not solved my issue. Everything seems to be well set, all access were granted in app manifest. Also I want to ask you, if you have some good and working example/tutorial of taking pictures with camera, please provide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is my code for camera capture, which works, I have a submitted app in the store:

```
private MediaCapture mediaCapture = null;
private async Task StartCapture()
{
  string error = null;

  try
  {
    if (mediaCapture == null)
    {
      mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
      mediaCapture.Failed += mediaCapture_Failed;

      var _deviceInformation = await GetCameraDeviceInfoAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);

      var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
      settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
      settings.PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview;
      settings.AudioDeviceId = "";
      if (_deviceInformation != null)
          settings.VideoDeviceId = _deviceInformation.Id;

      await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

      var focusSettings = new FocusSettings();
      focusSettings.AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.FullRange;
      focusSettings.Mode = FocusMode.Auto;
      focusSettings.WaitForFocus = true;
      focusSettings.DisableDriverFallback = false;

      mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(focusSettings);
      await mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.ExposureControl.SetAutoAsync(true);

      mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
      mediaCapture.SetRecordRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
    }

    captureReceipt.Source = mediaCapture;
    await mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    DisposeMediaCapture();
    error = ex.Message;
  }

  if (error != null)
  {
    await (new MessageBoxImpl()).ShowMessageAsync(error);
  }
}

private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraDeviceInfoAsync(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredPanel)
{

  DeviceInformation device = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
      .FirstOrDefault(d => d.EnclosureLocation != null && d.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredPanel);

  if (device == null)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "No suitable devices found for the camera of type {0}.", desiredPanel));
  }
  return device;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for snippet, but it just won't works. It gave me HResult of -2147024891, no inner exception and still access denied with System.UnauthorizedAccessException :/

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy also in the package manifest I have set the webcam capability, but I guess you have done it also ...

Comment: You can also download the example code for the "Building Apps for Windows Phone 8.1 Jump Start": https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=b36de4dd5a9179a1&id=B36DE4DD5A9179A1%2193175&ithint=folder,.zip&authkey=!APluMWf01e3WvqA
look for session 17, it is about camera

Comment: in Package.appxmanifest there are these
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
    <Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
    <Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates" />
    <Capability Name="videosLibrary" />
    <Capability Name="removableStorage" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="microphone" />
  </Capabilities>

and in StoreManifest.xml
      <Requirement Name="ID_REQ_REARCAMERA" />
      <Requirement Name="ID_REQ_FRONTCAMERA" />

Comment: @LászlóCitrusNagy did you try the session 17 example? I tried it and it also works for me

Comment: yup, tried already, didn't worked, so I just went angry and ported the code to WP8.0 already, where it works like a charm :)

Comment: I also have a developer preview installed on a HTC 8x .. and the emulator works as well ... so no idea what could be wrong with your setup ...

Comment: be careful with the autofocus settings. I suggest to put an "if (MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusChangedSupported) { }" around this part of the code. Some devices like the crappy Lumia 530 will crash without this check.

Comment: This code is working, but I want to Focus "continuously" like the original Camera app. Because I want to capture Barcodes and I need to focus them closely. Any solution?

Comment: any full example does have anyone?

Comment: @Jogy, is it possible to turn on both cameras at the same time, by creating two MediaCapture instances for the rear and front camera?

Comment: @robcsi I haven't tried, but I don't see why not - simply use different device id in MediaCaptureInitializationSettings.VideoDeviceId

Comment: @Jogy thanks for the answer, I tried in the meantime. It is not natively possible, due to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826839/how-to-display-the-preview-of-2-cameras-in-windows-8-using-the-mediacapture-clas.

On Windows, if you are using default settings then you are stuck with one camera only. To consume full features, you will require to develop your own controls, which means iterating over all devices natively, getting their streams, rendering their results as Image objects on a Canvas (say), and then capturing it (or at least saving the current pixels from screen) as image.