# MvvmCross PictureChooser Plugin is not working in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

I am developing an Windows Phone 8.1 app using MvvmCross. However, I am unable to use Picture Chooser Plugin.

Picture Chooser:

I am calling:

```
Stream tt= await priChooserTask.ChoosePictureFromLibraryAsync(1024, 95);
```

A File Picker will open choose file but the Stream is always null. await call never return stream.

I also tried the [PictureTaking](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/PictureTaking) sample, but it is not working on Windows phone 8.1 Stream is always null.

Comment: Same crap for me, i'll take a look on it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I had found [this article](http://www.mytakeon.net/post/2015/01/30/Using-the-MvvmCross-PictureChooser-plug-in-with-a-Windows-Phone-81-XAML-app), however it didnt work for me (i got some exceptions and camera stopped to work at all) so i needed to go deeper.

In MvxPictureChooserTask, i added

```
        var capture = new MediaCapture();
        await capture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings {PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Photo}); // New line
        await capture.StartPreviewAsync(); // New line
        await capture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(encoding, file);
```

but that didnt work for me either.

As i understood, there's no "chosers" in WP 8.1 anymore. We cant ask system "please, make a photo and return it to me" like it was in 8.0 and earlier. Now we have to create our own view with CaptureElement and MediaCapture. I dunno how to move that into a plugin yet, but if to talk about Windows implementation, [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25825398/windows-phone-8-1-camera-initialisation) works fine for me.

Edit: [here is another sample](http://wpcsharp.blogspot.fi/p/how-to-use-camera-in-wp-81-app.html) that works fine, but still it is WP 8.1.